# RavenDB - How can I do a structure of my database?

Tags: json, ravendb

I want to use the RavenDB. I want to do a system for administration news with comments.

I expect perhaps 500 comments in one news.

What is correct structure for news with comments? Whats type of cases can I use the following structures of the documents?

**1.) Comments are in the news object**

```
{
   "News": [
      {
         "NewsId": "1",
         "Title": "Name",
         "Content": "Text",
         "Comments": [
            {
               "CommentId": "1",
               "Comment": "Text"
            },
            {
               "CommentId": "2",
               "Comment": "Text"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**2.) News and comments are into separate objects:**

**News:**

```
{

   "News": [

      {

         "NewsId": "1",

         "Title": "Name",

         "Content": "Text",

         "CommentId": "1"

      }

   ]

}
```

**Comments:**

```
{
    "Comments": [
                {
                   "CommentId": "1",
                   "Comment": "Text"
                },
                {
                   "CommentId": "2",
                   "Comment": "Text"
                }
             ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will want to put this on separate objects, if you are accessing the news item without the comments.

Comment: Are the rules for create the structure of documents for different cases? (Best practice)

Comment: Yes, it depends on the access pattern and the transactional boundary. The docs talk about this quite often.